# Windows Batch File to copy yesterdays file without name change but failed in month of January

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

Sir,
       I have a batch file running in scheduler to copy yesterdays file from one folder to another folder and it was working fine. It has stopped working since 1st January. Script is given below. I was copying file name  B* from Y partition to folder d:\pqe*  folder

```
@echo off
set day=-1   
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)   
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)      
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"   
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"           
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"   
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"     

set "DD=%result:~6,2%"    
set "data=%mm%-%dd%-%yyyy%"      
echo Yesterday was "%data%"     
xcopy /y y:\B*.csv /S/D:%data% D:\pqe\* >>pqe.log    
echo copying to interfacePC >>pqe.log    
xcopy /y y:\B*.csv /S/D:%data% z:\*    
pause
```

Comment: cannot read what your batch file is supposed to look like.  please put 4 spaces in front of every line of your file, then paste into this page for best formatting.

Comment: What is appearing on your report `Yesterday was "????"` ?

Comment: If you mean files from yesterday or earlier, `forfiles` might be suitable for your needs: `forfiles /S /P "Y:\\" /M "B*.csv" /D -1 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE copy /Y /B @path "D:\\pqe\\"`

Comment: When I run this script on 8th January 2016, I get message in "pqe.log" file as follows

Yesterday was "01-07-2016" 
0 File(s) copied
copying to interfacePC 

Here yesterday date is perfect right. This file was working perfect upto 31st December, but has failed working from 1st January 2016.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Kory Gill and Mr Magoo, thanks a lot. Actually in new year file generated is starting with letter c, earlier it was like "BL00231.csv" but from new year it is generating name as "CA00001.csv". Thanks a lot for all of you, I just changed script as                                             xcopy /y y:\C*.csv /S/D:%data% D:\pqe\* >>pqe.log     and now it's working fine.